# jQuery Validation by Class Works! BUT Returns "property 'length' of null" Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, validation

This jQuery validation script if functioning correctly, however it returns an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" for EVERY keystroke entered, until ALL of the inputs have at least some value entered...

```
$(document).ready(function () {var counter=0;                       
$('body').on('input', function(){
var show = true;
// Check each child input for data.
$(this).find('.required').each(function(i){
    if($(this).val().length==0){
        show = false;
    };
});
if(show){
if(counter<=0){
```

What's even stranger is that even after an inputs value is deleted and then re-entered, the error messages stop and the code continues to function correctly. Having taught myself jQuery I am as interested in a solution, as I am in learning why this would occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't check length on `undefined` or `null`
try this

```
if(!($(this).val()){
  //youre code
}
```

this test will evaluate to **true** if value is :

```
null
undefined
NaN
empty string ("")
0
false
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Thanks Taha - code change fixed the error! For anyone else's future reference, the code used was: if(!$(this).val()){